# Error in training model for Faster-R-CNN implemented in Tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, neural-network

I am using the following github repository which implements a deep learning model called as Faster R-CNN in tensorflow:

https://github.com/smallcorgi/Faster-RCNN_TF

This model will be used for object detection.

I am trying to replicate the steps that are mentioned there to train a model and here is what I am facing:

1. I follow steps from 1 to 5 successfully.
2. Then, I run the command:

   **experiments/scripts/faster_rcnn_end2end.sh cpu 0 VGG16 pascal_voc**

And I get the error:

```
+ set -e
+ export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=True
+ PYTHONUNBUFFERED=True
+ DEV=cpu
+ DEV_ID=0
+ NET=VGG16
+ DATASET=pascal_voc
+ array=($@)
+ len=4
+ EXTRA_ARGS=
+ EXTRA_ARGS_SLUG=
+ case $DATASET in
+ TRAIN_IMDB=voc_2007_trainval
+ TEST_IMDB=voc_2007_test
+ PT_DIR=pascal_voc
+ ITERS=70000
++ date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S
+ LOG=experiments/logs/faster_rcnn_end2end_VGG16_.txt.2017-01-11_17-16-26
+ exec
++ tee -a experiments/logs/faster_rcnn_end2end_VGG16_.txt.2017-01-11_17-16-26
tee: experiments/logs/faster_rcnn_end2end_VGG16_.txt.2017-01-11_17-16-26: No such file or directory
+ echo Logging output to experiments/logs/faster_rcnn_end2end_VGG16_.txt.2017-01-11_17-16-26
Logging output to experiments/logs/faster_rcnn_end2end_VGG16_.txt.2017-01-11_17-16-26
+ python ./tools/train_net.py --device cpu --device_id 0 --weights data/pretrain_model/VGG_imagenet.npy --imdb voc_2007_trainval --iters 70000 --cfg experiments/cfgs/faster_rcnn_end2end.yml --network VGGnet_train
voc_2007_train
voc_2007_val
voc_2007_trainval
voc_2007_test
kitti_train
kitti_val
kitti_trainval
kitti_test
nthu_71
nthu_370
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tools/train_net.py", line 16, in <module>
    from networks.factory import get_network
  File "/home/impadmin/Desktop/Faster-RCNN_TF-master/tools/../lib/networks/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .VGGnet_train import VGGnet_train
  File "/home/impadmin/Desktop/Faster-RCNN_TF-master/tools/../lib/networks/VGGnet_train.py", line 2, in <module>
    from networks.network import Network
  File "/home/impadmin/Desktop/Faster-RCNN_TF-master/tools/../lib/networks/network.py", line 3, in <module>
    import roi_pooling_layer.roi_pooling_op as roi_pool_op
  File "/home/impadmin/Desktop/Faster-RCNN_TF-master/tools/../lib/roi_pooling_layer/roi_pooling_op.py", line 6, in <module>
    _roi_pooling_module = tf.load_op_library(filename)
  File "/home/impadmin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py", line 64, in load_op_library
    None, None, error_msg, error_code)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /home/impadmin/Desktop/Faster-RCNN_TF-master/lib/roi_pooling_layer/roi_pooling.so: undefined symbol: _Z22ROIPoolBackwardLaucherPKffiiiiiiiS0_PfPKiRKN5Eigen9GpuDeviceE
```

It looks like there is a problem in the creation of **roi_pooling.so** file. The file gets created successfully but it is showing this error.

Does it mean that the mentioned repository is meant for GPU based computations and not CPU based ?

How will I be able to run it on CPU only if possible ?